# QHeaderView::section:selected

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qheaderview

I have following style segment applied to QHeaderView

```
QHeaderView::section:selected
    {
        padding-left: 16px;
        background-color: #1c1c1c;
    }
```

for some reason "selected" Pseudo-State for QHeaderView is not working but in the documentation it says it should work. I have tried following and it works:

```
QHeaderView::section:first
{
    padding-left: 16px;
    background-color: #1c1c1c;
}
```

My question is, how can apply a different style for the selected Header TIA

Comment: Which version of Qt are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug on Qt4.7. It affects to `QHeaderView::section:checked` too. You can see:

- [this thread on Qt Center](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/46841-Can-t-style-QHeaderView-section-selected-in-QSS-stylesheet)
- [this bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-23689)

If you are using Qt4.7 you can try to upgrade to a newer version. Maybe the bug has been fixed in recent versions.